# android AsyncTask creation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest

I am trying to post some data via http post request and also to understand the whole process. I red documentation on android developers site, I have watched some youtube tutorials but I still have some points there that I am not familiar with. I found following login example code, but it wasnt in AsyncTask. I know it has to be. But when Im trying do do it with AsyncTask my parameters are bad defined and I am stuck. Can anyone pllllease help me and explain how it actually works if I want to pass some data to a .php script on http server? Here is my code: (After editing, here is my try with AsyncTask) :

```
 public class AndroidLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button ok,back,exit;
TextView result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_login);

 // Login button clicked
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    ok.setOnClickListener(this);

    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_android_login, menu);
    return true;
}

private class Login extends AsyncTask <String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/login.php");

        try {
            // Add user name and password
         EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
         String username = uname.getText().toString();

         EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
         String password = pword.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            Log.w("SENCIDE", str);

            if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
             Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE");
             result.setText("Login successful");   
            }else
            {
             Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE");
             result.setText(str);             
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is); 
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            // Read response until the end
            try {
             while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
               total.append(line); 
             }
            } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Return full string
            return total;

        return null;
    }


}

public void onClick(View view) {

    new Login().execute();
}
```

}

Comment: You want to know what going on with the second part of code or you want to know about working of AsyncTask ?

Comment: please read [AsyncTask reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: to be honest both things. I want to know how to put this into a AsyncTask and I also would like to know what is going on with the second partof code. :)

Comment: **"But when Im trying do do it with AsyncTask my parameters are bad defined and I am stuck."** - OK, so post your attempt to use `AsyncTask` - that is what your question is about isn't it?

Comment: I edited my question like you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the method signature `protected String doInBackground(String... params)` means that `params` needs to be a `String` array.

Secondly, don't ever do anything like the following in the `doInBackground(...)` method of an `AsyncTask`...

```
 EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
 String username = uname.getText().toString();

 EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
 String password = pword.getText().toString();
```

...the reason is that the `doInBackground(...)` method runs on a separate thread to the main (UI) thread and attempting to access UI elements such as the `EditText` widgets will cause an exception. Instead, move those lines of code to the `onClick(...)` method of the `Activity`. You can then pass the credentials to the `doInBackground(...)` method using the following (for example)...

```
new Login().execute(new String[] {username, password});
```

...then in the `doInBackground(String... params)` method, `params[0]` will be the username and `params[1]` will be the password.